# unable to clone repos from my second gitlab to my first gitlab through GUI interface of Gitlab

Tags: authentication, https, gitlab, clone

Need help! I am not able able clone Repos / project from my first gitlab to my second. I am getting error while using the import code on gitlab gui.

`The repository could not be imported.
Error importing repository https://gitlab1/GROUP/PROJECT.git into GROUP/PROJECT - Cloning into bare repository '[REPOS PATH]/GROUP/PROJECT.git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab2/GROUP/PROJECT.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the right SSL Certificate in the config. And look @ `/opt/gitlab/ssl/` if there are your certificates. Otherwise can you explain your problem a preciser?